# How to get a location's details using its placeId without needing to supply a HTML element?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm curious how you would get the details of a place using its placeId without needing to supply it an HTML element. For example, the documentation [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests) shows all of the examples needing an HTML element, but I simply need to call it to use the data elsewhere.

```
var request = {
  placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);

function callback(place, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    createMarker(place);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try google places api https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid='PLACE_ID'&key=YOUR KEY'

change json to xml if you need response in xml format

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch place details by [placeId](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id), in addition to providing a list of places within an area, the Places service can also return detailed information about a specific place. Once a place has been returned in a place search response, its place ID can be used to request additional details about that place, such as its complete address, phone number, user rating and reviews, etc.

The place ID provides a reliable means of referencing information for a particular place. A common way of using place IDs is to search for a place then use the returned place ID to retrieve place details.

Using the Google Places API Web Service, you can find a place ID by doing a [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) request.

```
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196},
zoom: 15
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.getDetails({
placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
}, function(place, status) {
if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: place.geometry.location
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
place.formatted_address + '</div>');
infowindow.open(map, this);
});
}
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you read the question. I didn't want to use any HTML to make any requests to the API.